# how to get this interface using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

i need to find this interface in visual studio using vb.net to use it as a booking tool for an hotel booking project.it's used select a square and show the booking form 
and to show select the number of square according to the number of booking days

it's the green part in this picture

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a 3rd party (Telerik or similar) who has controls built for this type of thing. It might be the quickest to get you up and running, but it comes with it's own issues - like not finding the support you need.

You can however put in some effort and use a default grid (recommended). This can be manually styled and adjusted to get the behaviors to the point where you need it to be (WPF exposes all you need).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

That's not one of the standard .Net controls, so you'd either need write it yourself, or buy it (if you can identify the vendor).